# Error: Cannot find module 'assets-webpack-plugin' on Jenkins

Tags: node.js, jenkins, npm, webpack, assets-webpack-plugin

Following error is seen while executing `webpack` as `jenkins` jobs.

```
webpack --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile

Error: Cannot find module 'assets-webpack-plugin'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:338:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:280:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:364:17)
    at require (module.js:380:17)
    at Object.<anonymous> 

npm ERR! Linux 3.16.0-33-generic
npm ERR! argv "/usr/bin/node" "/usr/bin/npm" "run" "build:dev"
npm ERR! node v0.10.45
npm ERR! npm  v2.15.1
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
```

Answer (score 0):

[This plugin didn't get installed due to incorrect `node` and `npm` version installed/used by `Jenkins`.](https://github.com/kriasoft/react-starter-kit/issues/420#issuecomment-175127383)

This scenario required following version upgrade on the ubuntu os on which jenkins is running:

- node - v6.x.x
- npm - v3.x.x

[image]